# "See Index Coverage" link from sitemap not working in Google Search Console (not able to click)

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, reporting, dead-links

For the last week, I've had this problem in Google search console.  The "see index coverage" link is not working. I'm not able to click it to see index and submitted URLs in sitemap.

I tried resubmitting the sitemap to all versions but it is still not working.

[image: image is here]

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! I am not sure how long it has been between submitting the sitemap and your checking, however, Google is notoriously slow. It could take several months before this links works. Cheers!!